# Flow - 'remembering' that if X is truthy, Y must be truthy

Tags: flowtype

Is is possible to get something like this working in flow?

```
const flag: boolean = false
const obj: ?string = flag ? "hello" : null

if (flag) {
  (obj: string) // Cannot cast `obj` to string because null or undefined is incompatible with string.
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAA8AuMAIzjhgFMBDbMAXjCjplxsxwLDnIBWZAPwEATgEtsAc2bEwwsACIAFjRjwlYMtgCuG9BKhgAFEQCUYAN6owp-kLDip086gC+QA

I've got a variable `obj` that's conditionally set if `flag` is true. Can I do anything so that flow 'remembers' that if `flag==true`, `obj` has been set?

Comment: Further experiments: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzFgEMBzALjACM44YBTY7MAXiOJl3tXwE8AHemAAqAV34NWYANpQOXADRhsomDAC6YAD4z8AJ1H0lBPQEtspdeix5CcKgCsxE+pWeS2JUmAD8ug0ZgAEQAFvRqcEGalLLygSpqVqimUGAAFPZO4gzSAAzqAJRgAN6oYOmZ7vTSAIzqlCbmpAWoAL7oPAJCwmSk9AAmAPKOUsX4ZJRB2HCCQUoAbhyGlAkwrdol4xTBvPT8c2CLMMtgjRbtNgRgW31Djm69A8MOUl6+mxM7ewdHJ6Hh8CC60oY0+Uxm9B+S1cylUa3QKXSNyejgAdFtWCw2EFdvsiqVymlkXcHKjfjCzs02kA   Looks like disjoint unions would be a possibility, unless anyone has a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast if you want to, but you are required to test against all other types first.

It's also recommended that you create a custom type for this, but I don't believe that is required here.

Here's a code example:

```
/* @flow */

type ObjectOrString = {}|string|null;

const x: boolean = false
const constObj:ObjectOrString = x ? "hello" : null
var obj:ObjectOrString = x ? "hello" : null

if ( obj && typeof obj === 'object' ) {
  let o = (obj:{});
}
if ( obj && typeof obj === 'string' ) {
  let o = (obj:string);
}

if ( constObj && typeof constObj === 'object' ) {
  let o = (constObj:{});
}
if ( constObj && typeof constObj === 'string' ) {
  let o = (constObj:string);
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDyARgFZ4DGGhATgMoY0CWAdgOZgC8YA3gL4AfAM6NWbASwCuMGAG50FOCxFgAHgC4wxOHBh4Ahiy5go+mELypFyjGGsiSpdY8rV6o9sdVgA-GABEABZ4MnD+YJpSMqgAbvo0YHBkzmSutAzMntzefkEh8OGR0jDoTFBgABSJZGAAZLVg2Phw5UmkXJzcAORtrl1gAJS8qGBgerZwxhVt6vwD8nyoZZXV7fWNuHgtqx3dIpls-UM8I2N4E1Mz+2LzqItL5VX21DXrTVvlz467YD2pVEdhqNxokpl9knMFg8VuC1g13ttYT8utd2ICTsDzqDuBVYepUWxbvdUEA